# How to make link and text be on the same level

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a test HTML site for a week now, in order to learn how to code HTML and CSS, and while working on it, i got stuck on a problem with the navigation, as i want to make the top text and the navigation links be on the same level, however they aren't. I tried fixing it on JSfiddle, but it showed it wrong and the problem continues.
Here's the code i used for the links and top text themselves:

```css
div.a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
}

header {
  background: #ff0000;
  float: left;
}

.jwimg {
  float: left;
}

.button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  font-size: 50px;
}

div.b {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 200%
}

.topnav {
  text-align: right;
  height: 0cm
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 200%;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="b">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
      <a class="link" href="ss"></a>
      <a href="">HOME</a>
      <a href="">GAMES</a>
      <a href="">VIDEOS</a>
      <a href="">CONTACT</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Title -->
  <h1>
    Joe's Pizza
  </h1>
</div>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use CSS's FLEXBOX property `align-items: baseline;`

You can achieve your wished results with the CSS [FLEXBOX](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) property [align-items](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp) as shown in the code snippet below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
* Use flexbox's align-items: baseline property, to achive your result
*/
nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 200%;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 25px;
  background-color: #000;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}

brand a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brand a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Joe's Pizza</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav>
      <div class="brand">
        <a href="#"><h1>Joe's Pizza</h1></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">GAMES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Additional comments and modifications

You forgot the `<li>` items in your `<ul>` tag so i added them.

I modified the code, so the brand is a link. With that, you could redirect the users from any location to the "HOME" page.

Since i expect, you don't want all the links to be `200%` on your entire page, i changed it to be that large in the nav only.

It is recommended, to split your page up into various different tags such as `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<footer>`, etc., so i combined the brand and the navigation items to be together in the `<nav>` tag.

[Here's my code](https://repl.it/repls/MenacingMundaneRotation#index.html), if you'd like to play around with it or modify it directly in the browser.